# Configuring wireless adsl modem/router to work as router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

My ISP has given me a wired broadband connection(adsl). I bought a new wireless adsl modem-router(dlink 2750u). I contacted ISP to check How I can install my new router. They said it wont work because they don't support **pppoe** and they use **mer**(MAC Encapsulation Routing).

I just wanted to know if there is any configuration for this to work.

Comment: If your ISP says the device you bought won't work on their service its because the device doesn't have the required features in order to do so.  At the end of the day you are at the mercy of your ISP in order to get an ip address assigned to this new adsl modem otherwise.  **Only your ISP can do that part.**

Comment: as @Ramhound says, you will need another device. if your current equipment doesn't support MER, that is.